# Approximate an array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of the form

```
[-0.87336,0.18776,1.00000,0.56449,-0.27645]
```

I would like to convert it to an array of the form

```
[-1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0]
```

following the rule that if the element i of the initial array is less or equal to -0.5, then it is assigned the number -1.0; if it is in the interval (-0.5,0.5) then it is assigned the value 0.0, and finally if it is greater or equal to 0.5, it is assigned the value 1.0.

I tried defining a function

```
def modulator(x):
    if -0.5<x<0.5:
        return 0
    elif 0.5<=x:
         return 1
    else:
         return -1
```

Then I did the assignment with the for loop

```
array_new = []
for el in array:
    ell = [modulator(i) for i in el]
    array_new.append(ell)
```

Is there a more elegant pythonic way to do this?
I though about np.where(), but I don't know how to handle the multiple conditionals.

Comment: You have the `numpy` tag. Is it a list or a numpy array?

Comment: Maybe `np.round()` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In numpy you could use `np.round`:

```
x = np.array([-0.87336,0.18776,1.00000,0.56449,-0.27645])

x.round()
```

which gives:

```
array([-1.,  0.,  1.,  1., -0.])
```

If you don't like the `-0.`, you can add `0.`:

```
x.round() + 0.
array([-1.,  0.,  1.,  1., 0.])
```

If your inputs go outside the range where `round` will work directly (*i.e.* the values in your example are between -1 and +1, but if they are too far beyond this), you could use `clip` first:

```
x = np.array([-2.87336, -.501, 7.18776, 99.00000, 0.499, 0.56449,-87.27645])

np.round( np.clip(x, -1, 1)) + 0.

array([-1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1., -1.])
```

As a check, I ran the following to cover the boundaries I was unsure of:

```
x = np.array([-0.87336, -.501, -.499, 0.18776, 1.00000, 0.499, 0.56449,-0.27645])

array([-1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.select` (this will take care of larger than 1 and smaller than -1 values too where round would fail):

```
a = np.array([-0.87336,0.18776,1.00000,0.56449,-0.27645])
np.select((a<=-0.5, a>=0.5),(-1.0,1.0),0.0)
#[-1.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built-in [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function for that

```
lst = [-0.87336,0.18776,1.00000,0.56449,-0.27645]
lst= [float(round(i)) for i in lst]
```

```
[-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Although his snippets are lists, I think his real application uses numpy arrays.

Comment: it shouldnt be that hard to modify his code to use that if its a numpy array though

Comment: You wouldn't use an explicit loop in numpy, would you?